# Alarm Manager using Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarmmanager

I am creating an android app to set alarm using broadcast receiver. Its working fine when the app is open but when I closed the app completely then there is no notification generated. How to resolve this issue?

**Broadcast Receiver class**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    System.out.println("Alarm Fired");
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    Toast.makeText(context,"ALarm fired",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} }
```

**Main Activity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//the timepicker object
TimePicker timePicker;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //getting the timepicker object
    timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarmTimePicker);

    //attaching clicklistener on button
    findViewById(R.id.buttonAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //We need a calendar object to get the specified time in millis
            //as the alarm manager method takes time in millis to setup the alarm
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                        timePicker.getHour(), timePicker.getMinute(), 0);
            } else {
                calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                        timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
            }


            setAlarm(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        }
    });
}

private void setAlarm(long time) {
    //getting the alarm manager
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    //creating a new intent specifying the broadcast receiver
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);

    //creating a pending intent using the intent
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);

    //setting the repeating alarm that will be fired every day
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}  }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">

    </receiver>
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question so we can see what's the issue

Comment: @shriduttkothari have added the code here. Please go through it.